# How to update a TYPO3 extension with composer?

Tags: typo3

How do I update a specific extension (and only this extension) in composer mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To update an extension you only need this command:

```
composer update <vendor/package>
```

If you want to update all dependencies in this extension as well, add the option `--with-all-dependencies`:

```
composer update <vendor/package> --with-all-dependencies
```

or in short form

```
composer update <vendor/package> -W
```

If you need to perform a major update which cannot be handled with the given version in the composer.json, you can use this command:

```
composer require <vendor/package>:"^versionString"
```

Notice that you **should not** use `composer update` without a package name since this updates all packages at once. If something is broken after such an update, you will need to revert the whole update. Also Git bisect is impossible to find the specific package update which broke.